# Why do I need to chkdsk my bitlocker encrypted vhd every time I mount it?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption, vhd

I've got a `.vhd` NTFS drive which is bitlocker encrypted.

At some point I guess a rogue power cycle or plain old random corruption got to it and I need to `chkdsk` it every time it's mounted. The process that now occurs is:

1. double-click the .vhd file.

   1.1.  It then shows up in explorer as the assigned drive (presumably remembered somewhere).

   1.2. explorer tries to browse to the location but you get the old "X:\ is not accessible, the parameter is incorrect". This is normal and fine afaik - just explorer trying to browse to folder not unlocked yet
2. click on the drive in explorer

   2.1. get the bitlocker prompt
3. enter the password correctly

   3.1 at this point, the drive disappears in explorer sidebar, although remains in the devices and drives
4. open an administrator command prompt and run `chkdsk /f x:`. Hit yes when prompted.

   4.1. chkdsk reports back with this info (anything redacted red is a non-zero number)

   4.2. the disk is now available as expected/desired and does not seem to have any problems. sha2 on all the files against mirror copies elsewhere (where available) suggest they are all intact.

The everything otherwise seems fine but this has to be done every time the disk is mounted. Is there a way to eliminate steps 3 and 4?

Pics:

1.1

[image]

1.2.

[image]

2.1.

[image]

3.1.

[image]

4.1.

[image]

Comment: I would try and perform the required steps to get Windows to forget the drive.

Comment: I haven't been able to find out much on what these required steps are. If you have any resources at hand would be appreciated!